# PHP code line break `\n` causing gap between elements

Tags: php

I'm echoing a series of HTML elements using PHP. I'm using `\n` to cause code line breaks to make the source code more organized and legible.

For some reason, the use of `\n` in a specific location is causing a mysterious gap between the HTML elements. In firebug, this gap is not showing up as a margin, or padding, but rather just a gap.

**Here is the PHP in question:**

Note: As you can see, I have removed all of the PHP inside the tags as I'm pretty sure it is not relevant to this problem.

```
echo '<ul ... >'."\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_pag_data)) {

    echo '<li><a ... >'."\n".
                '<img ... >'."\n".
          '</a></li>'."\n"; <---- THIS IS THE \n THAT SEEMS TO BE CAUSING THE GAP
}
echo '</ul>'."\n";
```

Have you ever seen anything like this before, a presentation gap associated with PHP line breaks?
If so, what is the reason for it?

Is it really that important that I use `\n` in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal. A `\n` line break has no meaning in HTML, so it's interpreted as a space character. If you don't want that gap, then eliminate the `\n`, or rewrite the html so it's not relevant:

```
<li><a ...><img ...></a></li>
```

As a general rule, tags which can contain text should never have their closing tags on a line by themselves, for this very reason.

---

Following up on your 'where to put \n' question. This comes down to personal preference, but I tend to format my html like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td><a href="some big long ugly url">
           <img ....></a></td>
</tr>
```

Since `<tr>` can't contain any text on its own (in valid html), it's ok to put on its own line. But the `</a>` and `</td>` are both tags that CAN contain text, so I put them right up against the end of the 'text' (the img tag in this case), so that the Phantom Linebreak Menance (coming soon to a starwars ripoff near you) can't strike.

Note, of course, that my example does have a line break and indentation between the opening `<a>` and the `<img>` tag, so that's another place where a "must be right next to each" other layout would cause a gap. If you need a series of things lined up smack dab against each other, than you basically can't use line breaks anywhere in that section of the page.

Comment: Well that completely makes sense. Thanks a bunch. So if you were I in this case, and you were creating an image gallery as I am with the code in question, where would you place the line breaks? Would you place them at all? Is it good practice to use `\n` in your PHP code, or is it just superfluous?

Comment: See followup. In general, it's a good idea to generate readable HTML while debugging/building a site. Once it's working properly, you can use a minifier to save a few bytes by removing the indent tabs/spaces/linbreaks.

Comment: Excellent followup and comment. So you would remove the `\n` before the site goes live anyway?

Comment: I leave it in on my sites. The extra couple $ in bandwidth bills isn't worth the hassle of adding/removing them each time you're testing something. And as a point of pride, I always want readable html going out on the wire.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace is translated into (empty) HTML text nodes, which take up some space (you can test this by walking the DOM). There is no solution to make these disappear that I know of other than removing the whitespace from your HTML in the first place.

Of course it's not only `\n` that would cause this behavior; spaces or tabs would do exactly the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular case the newlines are used to *prettify the html source*, keep it readable via view-source. That's quite common actually. (Yet redundant.)

As said by the other answers, it does not have meaning normally. Albeit this can be overriden via CSS and the attribute (which we can assume is not the case here):

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that by using the css `white-space`, I can remove the gap in question?

Comment: It's not very likely. But look into a CSS inspector for calculated attributes. Maybe you find a related attribute. A single space or newline might add enough movement by itself however.

Comment: That I will. Thanks very much. In the end, maybe I'm going a bit crazy on the `\n`. I don't think my code will suffer that much if I leave a few of them out.

Answer (score 0):

You should only output a newline where you in fact want a newline in the output. In HTML, a newline is whitespace, just like the space character.